# How to use std::insert in 2d map in c++?

Tags: c++

I'm having some problems getting `std::insert()` to work on a 2D map.  It works fine when I use the map as normal, but I can't seem to get the syntax quite right when using a map inside another map and was wondering if someone could help.
I would like the 2nd map to be unchanged for the time being:

```
string prevValue;
std::map <string, map <string, int > > mCounts;
mCounts.insert (std::pair  <string, map <string, int>>(prevValue, map <string, int>);
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a "temporary value" set of parentheses:

```
mCounts.insert (
    std::pair  <string, map <string, int>>(prevValue, map <string, int>());
//                                                                     ^^
```

Here are a few alternatives:

```
mCounts.insert(std::make_pair("foo", std::map<std::string, int>()));
mCounts.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
                std::forward_as_tuple("bar"), std::forward_as_tuple());
mCounts["quz"];
```

And in C++17:

```
mCounts.try_emplace("zip");
```